# UDT socket send() in blocking mode returns error code

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, udp-data-transfer

I am writing a program using [UDT (UDP-based Data Transfer Protocol)](http://udt.sourceforge.net) sockets.
I created socket with default settings (which according to documentation has blocking read/write with infinite timeout).
However, during my iterative calls to UD::send() function, after a few first calls I receive the following error for calling send() function:

```
ETIMEOUT 6003 Timeout on UDT_SNDTIMEO .
```

according to documentation this error is for when the timeout happens, but in my case the timeout is "-1" which means infinite wait. I checked the parameters of UDT socket with getsockopt() and they are all as supposed to be. ("-1" for UDT_SNDTIMEO & UDT_RCVTIMEO, and "true" for UDT_SNDSYN & UDT_RCVSYN)
I am using the latest version of UDT (4.11), and my platform is Linux CentOS 6.4
Any thoughts or input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get -1 from? Infinite socket timeouts are usually indicated by zero.

Comment: @EJP UDT sockets use -1 for indicating infinite timeout, as in documentation [here](http://udt.sourceforge.net/udt4/index.htm), in functions>setsockopt() reference page.

Comment: Very strange. Why did they do that, I wonder, when `::setsockopt()` uses zero? People should not reinvent the wheel.